# Mysql query update multiple columns error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to upload multiple columns at once with this code:

```
    function updateMultiple($idElement,$arrayFieldValues=""){

        $toSave=$arrayFieldValues?$arrayFieldValues:$_POST;

        foreach($toSave as $field => $value) {
                    if (strpos($field, 'save_') === 0) {
                        $field = str_replace('save_', '', $field);
                        $updateString .= $field."='".addslashes($value)."', ";
                    }
                }
        $updateString = substr_replace($updateString ,"",-2);

       $query="UPDATE ".$this->tab."
            SET ".$updateString.", lastUser='".$usrId."'
            WHERE ".$colName." = '".$idElement."'";
            $this->execute($query);
   }
```

However I get this error:

```
PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET Country='England', FirstName='John', LastName='Smith', lastUser='10' ' at line 2
```

But to me it all seems right!

Comment: Output the query before executing and look at that. Trying to determine what it looks like with your returns and formatting can be difficult. Looking at what PHP actually thinks the query looks like can usually help you debug.

Comment: Does `$this->tab` return anything. My guess is not.

Comment: I think he echoed it, saw the problem and never returned.

Comment: Yes I returned! It just took me awhile.. And @Leeish was right! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from Tim's answer, you should be using `Prepared Statements`. Look at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for examples and further documentation. In summary, instead of `$query="UPDATE ".$this->tab." SET ".$updateString.", lastUser='".$usrId."' WHERE ".$colName." = '".$idElement."'";` use:

```
$query = 'UPDATE '.$this->tab.' SET lastUser = :user WHERE '.$colName.' = :colvalue'; 
$pdo->execute(array(:user => $usrId, :colvalue => $idElement));
```

You may further want to use transactions, but that's an exercise left to the reader.

Comment: By the way, Thank's for the suggestion, the way you are suggesting seems actually cleaner, I'll try!

Comment: Good man, @ghego1, if it works for you, I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer instead of the one you've already accepted.

Answer (score 0):

<s>You're missing a . between UPDATE and SET.
Hmm, maybe. In any case, the SQL being sent to PDO is incorrect. It's missing the UPDATE keyword.</s>
Check the comment.

Comment: I think he's missing a space between the table name and the set. He has the . after tab no?

Comment: Not true, he has a space, new line + tab|space. So this is not the problem.

Comment: I think it's all the problem. LOL. The point is, it's just a trivial syntax issue. The error message shows the fault.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide a value for each column in your sql statement. 
try this code:

```
$query="UPDATE ".$this->tab." SET ".$updateString."='yourString' , lastUser='".$usrId."'
        WHERE ".$colName." = '".$idElement."'";
```

Comment: I am guessing his update string contains `Country='England', FirstName='John', LastName='Smith'` which is just riddle with potential issues. I bet his `$this->tab` is empty string or something. Won't know unless he posts the output to what the query looks like before it executes.

Comment: he is writing the code like this: 
"UPDATE ".$this->tab." SET ".$updateString.", lastUser='".$usrId."'
        WHERE ".$colName." = '".$idElement."'";
Note that the column $updateString has no value in this code!

Comment: @Leeish you were right! Sorry guys, it's probably to late.. I had completely forgot to set it...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$query="UPDATE news SET title='$title', date='$date', body='$body' WHERE newsID=$ID
```